# Action of splittings on group cohomology of semidirect product

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let
$$1 \to A \to A \rtimes G \to G \to 1$$
be a semidirect product of groups, and let $K$ be a $G$-module. The quotient $q: A \rtimes G \to G$ makes $K$ into a $A \rtimes G$-module also.
For every splitting $\psi: G \to A \rtimes G$, we have a map
$$\psi^\ast: H^*(A \rtimes G, K) \to H^*(G,K).$$
Such splittings are a torsor over $H^1(G,A)$.

**Question:** Given $\phi \in H^1(G,A)$, is there an expression for $$(\phi\cdot \psi)^* -\psi^*: H^*(A \rtimes G, K) \to H^*(G,K)$$ in terms of $\phi$?

An answer when $A$ is abelian, $K$ has trivial $G$-action, and only considering $H^2(-,K)$ (that is, group extensions) would suffice for the application I have in mind.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation a bit? I'm mildly confused because $\phi$ and $\psi$ do not look composable in any order.

Comment: @DenisT. By $\phi \cdot \psi$, I mean the action of $\phi \in H^1(G,A)$ on the set of splittings $\{\psi: G \to A \rtimes G\}$, applied to $\psi$. I do not know if there is a better notation for this.